# How do I reverse this CSS rotate animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this CSS animation which I'm trying to reverse the animation of based on a class being added to a DOM node. I've tried multiple things but with no avail. Here is the code I'm using, see below:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/890/)

```
    // Closed state
    @-moz-keyframes spin-close { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-0deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin-close { 100% {  -webkit-transform: rotate(-0deg); } }
    @keyframes spin-close { 100% { transform:rotate(-0deg); } }

    // Open state
    @-moz-keyframes spin-open { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin-open { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); } }
    @keyframes spin-open { 100% { transform:rotate(-90deg); } }
```

I don't know whether I'm looking at it all wrong? Please advise(a demo would be awesome).

Comment: Yes, a demo would be awesome. Can we see one please?

Comment: Post some more code where you have applied this CSS so we can apply to it.

Comment: @Adsy ...see here for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/890/

Comment: @ShoaibChikate http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/890/

Comment: What is meaning of reverse?? In your demo your are rotating image in left side after we hover the img element. So when you dont have hover at that time do u want to rotate back to original position with animation or something else?? I am not clear about the requirement.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Yes exactly. When I hover off the image I want it to animate it back to its original position of 0deg

Comment: You have given removeClass for hover event only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't bother with javascript or animations. Use a CSS transition for this:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    transition:all 1s ease-out;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.image:hover {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/892/

Comment: If you get flickering on your iPhone with CSS animations, use: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the rotation, you can simply change the degree value to the opposite value. For example, if the element is currently rotated 45 degrees clockwise, you can reverse the rotation by rotating it -45 degrees.

```
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```